# Using VBA to change z order kills animation triggers (powerpoint)

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, z-order

I have a sub to import an image and place it behind a square which then disappears when clicked (disappear animation triggered on click).

But after I run the sub the trigger stops working. After a lot of searching I found it is caused by the section that changes the Z order. If I remove this part of the sub everything works fine but unfortunately that is not much use as the image is in front of the square that is supposed to reveal it.

I'm pretty new to this so if anyone can shed any light on this (or even better suggest a solution!) I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Matt

```
 Dim mySld As Slide
 Dim myShp As ShapeRange
 Dim i As Integer

 Set mySld = ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(256)

 Set myShp = mySld.Shapes.Paste

    With myShp
        .Name = "Quiz_Image_" & i
        .Left = 70
        .Top = 75
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = 425
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With

If myShp.Height > 275 Then
    myShp.Height = 275
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, setting the ZOrder, resets the trigger. The only option that I can think of (unless someone else points out a better solution) is to initiate the animation from the code it self using `.AnimationSettings`. For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim mySld As Slide
    Dim myShp As ShapeRange
    Dim i As Integer

    Set mySld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    Set myShp = mySld.Shapes.Paste

    With myShp
        .Name = "Quiz_Image_" & i
        .Left = 70
        .Top = 75
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = 425
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With

    If myShp.Height > 275 Then
        myShp.Height = 275
    End If

    mySld.Shapes("Shape Name").AnimationSettings.Animate
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Also see this interesting [read](http://skp.mvps.org/pptxp012.htm#interactive)

Comment: That is really helpful. Thank you for such a quick answer and works a charm. The only issue (please don't feel you have to answer - you have been very helpful already) is that there are actually 20 squares to animate. Is there any way to do a version of .Shapes([the one I just clicked on]).AminationSettings.Animate? Obviously I can just write a separate sub for each one but it seems rather in elegant!

Comment: You can you `.Selection.ShapeRange(1)` to get the current shape. You may want to see [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745871.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help - it took hours to get that far and I thought it might all have been wasted.